# UrbanAirship/Push notifications registration: NSURLErrorDomain: bad url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, urbanairship.com, afnetworking

I've got this really strange response to an MSMutableURLRequest:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL"
```

The URL is composed thusly. Yes I know I'm putting my testing device's token online. I've changed a digit for privacy.

```
self.pushTokenData = deviceToken;

NSURL *correctURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/device_tokens/2d1535dfcbfd859b4f55e6b74db24c71cf6082b503d38583b0b20f2816c24ca8"];

NSString *password = [@"redacted" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:correctURL];

NSLog(@"httpClient url: %@", [httpClient baseURL]);
[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"redacted" password:password];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:nil parameters:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
}];
[operation start];
```

This URL works fine in safari. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason your not using Urban Airship's iOS library? (http://urbanairship.com/docs/airship_lib.html)

Comment: Ignorance :) Now I know about it and I'll totally use it. Any clue what's going on above tho? It concerns me.

Comment: Urban Airship's lib is extremely bloated, and I strongly recommend against it. It's difficult to set up and it adds an extra 1MB to your app download.

Comment: @mattt, it might be bloated but I've never found it difficult to set up. The docs are quite useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[payload setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"], [[UIDevice currentDevice] model], [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier], nil] forKey:@"tags"];
[payload setValue:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] name] forKey:@"tz"];

NSString *deviceTokenString = [[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

AFHTTPClient *urbanAirshipClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/device_tokens/]];
urbanAirshipClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
[urbanAirshipClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:<# UA Application Key #> password:<# UA Application Secret #>];
[urbanAirshipClient putPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"device_tokens/%@", deviceTokenString] parameters:payload success:<# Success Block #> failure:<# Failure Block #>];
```

Try this.

Comment: Tried it. Works! Thanks. Got an error but I fixed it. the url ends up having device_tokens twice. Otherwise worked great. But what was I doing wrong above?

Comment: No idea what was wrong with the original, actually. Ah well, glad that works!

Comment: Is it because it was a PUT? Can I do a put that way?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and it turned out to be the result of an overly strict ad-blocker on the network.